# C# in mono, having trouble with ZIP file extraction

Tags: c#, mono, zip

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int important = rnd.Next ();
string finalpath = To + "/" + important + "/";
var archive = ArchiveFactory.Open (path);
foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
{
    if (!entry.IsDirectory)
    {
        entry.WriteToDirectory(finalpath, SharpCompress.Common.ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | SharpCompress.Common.ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
    }
}
```

This is my code and this is the error message that keeps popping up:

> Unhandled Exception: SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibException:
>   Bad state (invalid distance code)   at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.InflateManager.Inflate (FlushType
>   flush) <0x40dc0850 + 0x009a3> in :0    at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibCodec.Inflate (FlushType flush)
>   <0x40dc07a0 + 0x0002f> in :0    at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibBaseStream.Read (System.Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf3c0 + 0x002b3> in :0    at SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.DeflateStream.Read
>   (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf340 +
>   0x00047> in :0    at
>   SharpCompress.IO.ListeningStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf110 + 0x0003c> in :0
>   at SharpCompress.Utility.TransferTo (System.IO.Stream source,
>   System.IO.Stream destination) <0x40dbf070 + 0x0006f> in :0    at SharpCompress.Utility.Extract[TEntry,TVolume]
>   (SharpCompress.TEntry entry, SharpCompress.Archive.AbstractArchive`2
>   archive, System.IO.Stream streamToWriteTo) <0x40dbd1c0 + 0x00127> in
>   <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SharpCompress.Archive.Zip.ZipArchiveEntry.WriteTo (System.IO.Stream
>   streamToWriteTo) <0x40dbd170 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SharpCompress.Archive.IArchiveEntryExtensions.WriteToFile
>   (IArchiveEntry entry, System.String destinationFileName,
>   ExtractOptions options) <0x40dbd040 + 0x000dc> in <filename unknown>:0
>   at SharpCompress.Archive.IArchiveEntryExtensions.WriteToDirectory
>   (IArchiveEntry entry, System.String destinationDirectory,
>   ExtractOptions options) <0x40dbcd20 + 0x0016b> in <filename unknown>:0
>   at MainWindow.unpack (System.String path) [0x00070] in
>   /home/jan/Plocha/AUDIT2/AUDIT2/MainWindow.cs:52    at
>   MainWindow.<OnButton4Clicked>m__0 () [0x00259] in
>   /home/jan/Plocha/AUDIT2/AUDIT2/MainWindow.cs:459    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object
>   state) <0x7f99d04b11e0 + 0x00099> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f99d04afa20 + 0x0016e> in <filename
>   unknown>:0    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f99d04af9f0 + 0x00020> in <filename
>   unknown>:0    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   <0x7f99d04af940 + 0x00059> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x7f99d04b13a0 +
>   0x0002e> in <filename unknown>:0  [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibException: Bad state (invalid
>   distance code)   at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.InflateManager.Inflate (FlushType
>   flush) <0x40dc0850 + 0x009a3> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibCodec.Inflate (FlushType flush)
>   <0x40dc07a0 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.ZlibBaseStream.Read (System.Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf3c0 + 0x002b3> in <filename
>   unknown>:0    at SharpCompress.Compressor.Deflate.DeflateStream.Read
>   (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf340 +
>   0x00047> in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   SharpCompress.IO.ListeningStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count) <0x40dbf110 + 0x0003c> in <filename unknown>:0
>
>   at SharpCompress.Utility.TransferTo (System.IO.Stream source,
>   System.IO.Stream destination) <0x40dbf070 + 0x0006f> in <filename
>   unknown>:0    at SharpCompress.Utility.Extract[TEntry,TVolume]
>   (SharpCompress.TEntry entry, SharpCompress.Archive.AbstractArchive`2
>   archive, System.IO.Stream streamToWriteTo) <0x40dbd1c0 + 0x00127> in
>   :0    at
>   SharpCompress.Archive.Zip.ZipArchiveEntry.WriteTo (System.IO.Stream
>   streamToWriteTo) <0x40dbd170 + 0x0002b> in :0    at
>   SharpCompress.Archive.IArchiveEntryExtensions.WriteToFile
>   (IArchiveEntry entry, System.String destinationFileName,
>   ExtractOptions options) <0x40dbd040 + 0x000dc> in :0
>   at SharpCompress.Archive.IArchiveEntryExtensions.WriteToDirectory
>   (IArchiveEntry entry, System.String destinationDirectory,
>   ExtractOptions options) <0x40dbcd20 + 0x0016b> in :0
>   at MainWindow.unpack (System.String path) [0x00070] in
>   /home/jan/Plocha/AUDIT2/AUDIT2/MainWindow.cs:52    at
>   MainWindow.m__0 () [0x00259] in
>   /home/jan/Plocha/AUDIT2/AUDIT2/MainWindow.cs:459    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object
>   state) <0x7f99d04b11e0 + 0x00099> in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f99d04afa20 + 0x0016e> in :0    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   Boolean preserveSyncCtx) <0x7f99d04af9f0 + 0x00020> in :0    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
>   <0x7f99d04af940 + 0x00059> in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () <0x7f99d04b13a0 +
>   0x0002e> in :0  Aplikace byla ukončena signálem:
>   SIGHUP

Can you please help me?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: `mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b Wed Mar 16 13:19:08 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
`

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade to Mono 4.4 (or even try the nightly builds of master branch) because there have been many fixes on `System.IO.Compression` after version 4.2.3: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/5a422039ecf77a3d8c963e273c68b5c3e7c03bd8, for example this one: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/5a422039ecf77a3d8c963e273c68b5c3e7c03bd8